# StreamingResponseBody file download not work on Firefox

Tags: java, spring, reactjs

So I have a class on Java spring framework that will return a StreamingResponseBody type to the front-end (ReactJS) and the browser will automatically download the file. It works well on Google Chrome and Opera, but it isn't working on Firefox. Can someone help me with this? The file is an excel file.
Snippet of some important code:

```
Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
...
response.setContentType("application/excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"rolematrix-reports.xls\"");
return outputStream -> {
    workbook.write(outputStream);
};
```